# windows prompt doesn't recognizes jupyter as a command

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, command-prompt

I just had installed python in my laptop to work with some *brazilian labor microdata* then, following a tutorial on youtube I've installed some libs like pandas, matplotlib, numpy and jupyter notebook. And there is my problem.

> The tutorial said to do `pip install jupyter`

> and after, to run it `jupyter notebook`

but this happened at the command prompt

> ```
>    jupyter : O termo 'jupyter' não é reconhecido como nome de cmdlet,
>    função, arquivo de script ou programa operável. Verifique a grafia do
>    nome ou, se um caminho tiver sido incluído, veja se o caminho está
>    correto e tente novamente.
>    No linha:1 caractere:1
>    + jupyter noteboook
>    + ~~~~~~~
>    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (jupyter:String) [], Com
>    mandNotFoundException
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
> ```

> well, the error message is in portuguese because I'm brazilian, but it means something like: "*jupyter  isn't recognize as a name of cmdlet, function, script file or program. Check the spelling of the name or, if there is a path that had to be included, see if it's correct and try again*"

I've already tried to ins``tall **jupyterlab**, and running it as jupyterlab and had the same thing.

Don't know what to do and it's my very first time using Jupyter.

Comment: When you ran `pip install jupyter`, it should have printed a message saying a certain path was not in your `PATH`. Add that path to `PATH` and restart your Powershell session. You might have to restart Windows.

Comment: oh, this solved the problem of the warnings, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed virtual environment make sure you are in that directory before you open jupyter notebook.

using pip freeze you can check which package is installed.

If you have not installed virtual environment I strongly suggest to do so its quite easy.

command - python -m venv